# How set request timeout setting in firefox sdk?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, timeout, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to make `POST` request from a Firefox addon

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request; 
Request({
 url: "http://127.0.0.1/api",
 content:    "test",
 onComplete: function (response) {
 console.error("onComplete " + response.status);
 }
}).post();
```

but `onComplete` never runs. How i may fix this?
Set `network.http.response.timeout = 5` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this with the addon SDK stuff. The SDK has no `.timeout` options.

You can use `nsIXMLHttpRequest` directly for a workaround.

```
var {XMLHttpRequest} = require("sdk/net/xhr/");
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
// OR
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var req = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
  .createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
// AND
req.timeout = 5;
req.addEventListener("load", ...);
req.addEventListener("timeout", ...);
req.addEventListener("error", ...);
...
```

Comment: Please note that instead of `require("chrome");` you could also use [`net/xhr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/net_xhr).